# Xamarin Binding to control with Converter

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to create a text box (Editor) where as the person types in it, it decrements a number of characters remaining and shows, for example:  "56 characters remaining" in a Label.  I know how to write the Converter , but at the moment the **value** parameter when the Converter is called is **null**.  The **parameter** to the Converter is **200** as expected.  Even if I remove the Editor Binding and set it's Text="Hello", the value is still null when the Converter is called.

The Label and Editor are defined as follows:

```
<Label 
    BindingContext="{x:Reference CommentEditor}"
    Text="{Binding Path=Text, 
    Converter={StaticResource CharactersRemainingConverter}, ConverterParameter=200}"/>

<Editor 
    x:Name="CommentEditor"
    Text="{Binding Comment}" 
    Placeholder="Comment up to 200 characters" 
    MaxLength="200">
</Editor>
```

Can anyone see what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could change like this:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:CharactersRemainingConverter x:Key="charactersRemainingConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<Label 
   BindingContext="{x:Reference CommentEditor}"
   Text="{Binding Path=Text.Length, 
   Converter={StaticResource charactersRemainingConverter}, ConverterParameter=200}"/>

<Editor 
   x:Name="CommentEditor"
   Text="{Binding Comment}" 
   Placeholder="Comment up to 200 characters" 
   MaxLength="200">
</Editor>
```

in your **CharactersRemainingConverter** :

```
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} characters remaining",(int.Parse((string)parameter) - (int)value));
    }
```

Comment: Works thanks.  Did not realise I could access the ".Length" property of the Text like that.  Marked as answer.